# I need regular expression for HTML comment which contains any word

Tags: c#, regex

I want to remove HTML comments from my page, below is the format of comment

```
<!-- saved from url=(0116)file://D:\Documents and Settings\213039755\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\OLK5\abc.htm -->
```

I want regex for HTML comments which contains "Saved" word.

Currently I am using

```
Regex.Replace(content, "(?<=\\<!--\\s*save\\s*-->)", "sss");
```

Comment: Wrapping the entire regex into a `(?<= )` group won't do anything more than give you trouble.

Comment: Yes, [`(?<= )` is a bookbehind group, it asserts position after your match, then replaces a null position.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618) See the answer below, which does what you need correctly.

Comment: Your second `\\s*` will match only zero-or-more whitespace, not letters etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(content, @"<!-- saved[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Comment: @PramodGupta [Are you sure it's not working? This demo says otherwise.](http://regex101.com/r/lJ4yH4/1)

Comment: I also tested and verified the regex before posting (using this tool http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: Yes Its not working and when I am using     Regex.Replace(content, "<!--(.*?)-->", ""); it is removing all comments